# getting the value from the gridview cell in dynamic fields using row updating event

Tags: entity-framework, webforms

I'm trying to get the value from gridview but i get empty string.

this is UI:

```
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GroceryGrid"
    ItemType="DAL.Grocery" DataKeyNames="GroceryId"
    SelectMethod="GroceryGrid_GetData"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-responsive" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True"
    AutoGenerateEditButton="True" OnRowDeleting="GroceryGrid_RowDeleting" 
    OnRowEditing="GroceryGrid_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GroceryGrid_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="GroceryName" HeaderText="GroceryName"/>
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="Cup" HeaderText="Cup" />
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="Spoon" HeaderText="Spoon" />
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="Gram" HeaderText="Gram"/>
        <asp:DynamicField DataField="Piece" HeaderText="Piece"/>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

and its getting data correctly

```
     protected void GroceryGrid_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = GroceryGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        int groceryId = Convert.ToInt32(GroceryGrid.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
        string imeNamirnice = row.Cells[0].Text;
        double salica = Convert.ToInt32((row.Cells[2].Text));
        double zlica = Convert.ToInt32((row.Cells[3].Text));
        double gram = Convert.ToInt32((row.Cells[4].Text));
        double komad = Convert.ToInt32((row.Cells[5].Text));
        using (RwaContext update = new RwaContext())
```

this is the part of the code that is trying to get value from cells, but i get empty values 
such as

```
string imeNamirnice = row.Cells[0].Text;
```

it returns: "" - empty string

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, you are close. Showed a few different ways to get the DataKey value depending if you're updating or editing.

Front-End

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="id" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" CausesValidation="false" ShowEditButton="true" EditText="Edit Me" UpdateText="Update Me"/>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

        </div>
    </form>
```

Code-Behind

```
    public partial class MyProduct
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string sku { get; set; }
    }

public partial class _testForPw : BaseStorePage
{

    protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Collection<MyProduct> products = new Collection<MyProduct>();
        products.Add(new MyProduct() { id = "123", name = "Test123", sku = "Sku1234" });
        GridView1.DataSource = products;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        string id = (string)GridView1.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Value;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
        {
            // convert to integer and then execute code
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        string id = (string)GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
        {
            // convert to integer and then execute code
        }
    }
}
```